# XSL transformation not working in Apache camel application when deployed in JBoss eap 6.2 GA

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, apache-camel, jboss6.x

I have a Apache camel application which talks with a web service. I need to transform/un-marshal the response soap message into the proxy object. I am not using soap data format, instead I am using jaxb transformation and for that I need to first extract the xml from the soap message. The following xsl and soap response works fine when I run my application from command line, but it fails if I deploy my application on JBoss eap 6.2 GA. My xsl, sample response soap message and generated xml are as follows,

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/s:Envelope/s:Body/*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The sample soap message is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="8877bd15-990e-465f-acca-3b2f21945735"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">b0480ae4-7692-4224-9082-662cbe8a6edc</ActivityId>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <GetUserByEmailResponse xmlns="urn:RetailApi/AccountManagementService/v2">
        <GetUserByEmailResult xmlns:a="urn:RetailApi/Schemas/v2"
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:EmailAddress>a@b.com</a:EmailAddress>
            <a:FirstName>Scott</a:FirstName>
            <a:LastName>Tiger</a:LastName>
            <a:MobilePhoneNumber>3232326565</a:MobilePhoneNumber>
            <a:Title>Mr</a:Title>
            <a:UserId>xxxxx</a:UserId>
        </GetUserByEmailResult>
    </GetUserByEmailResponse>
</s:Body>
```

Generated xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>< xmlns="urn:RetailApi/AccountManagementService/v2"><><a:EmailAddress xmlns:a="urn:RetailApi/Schemas/v2">a@b.com</a:EmailAddress><a:FirstName xmlns:a="urn:RetailApi/Schemas/v2">Scott</a:FirstName><a:LastName xmlns:a="urn:RetailApi/Schemas/v2">Tiger</a:LastName><a:MobilePhoneNumber xmlns:a="urn:RetailApi/Schemas/v2">3232326565</a:MobilePhoneNumber><a:Title xmlns:a="urn:RetailApi/Schemas/v2">Mr</a:Title><a:UserId xmlns:a="urn:RetailApi/Schemas/v2">xxxx</a:UserId></></>
```

As you can see, the resultant xml have several issues. There is a space between **< xmlns**. At the end there are couple of blank/empty nodes like < / >< / >. Also, the couple of node are missing. i.e. **GetUserByEmailResponse** and **GetUserByEmailResult**, instead I get a blank node like **<>**.

After deploying and running the code on jboss app server, I get : `com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) in prolog, after '<'.`

This issue only happens when I run my application through application server and doesn't occur when i run as a standalone app.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of digging/debugging, I surrendered and chose the straight forward but not so clean solution. I wrote a utility method to extract the xml using String API. And this worked like a charm.

Comment: Hi, i am also facing the same issue. can you please tell me how you did ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to why your XSLT generates spaces that only validates when running JBoss.

However, another way to solve your use case would be a simple xpath and not involve XSLT at all.

```
final Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
from("foo:bar")
  .setBody(ns.xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[1]",String.class)
  // do whatever
```

SpringWS and CXF can handle this stuff pretty much automatic as well, if you would consider these components.

Comment: Thank you @Petter, but no luck with this solution as well :(